# Center position: relative div

Tags: html, css

So, I'm using this code: http://codepen.io/n7best/pen/EtFcH/

This is a roulette, I would like to have it (div `.spinner`) centered in bootstrap `.col-lg-12` div. 

I tried `text-align: center`, `margin-left/right:auto`, `margin-leftcalc(50%-29em)` but none of them seems to work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to center a relative element :

```
.spinner {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -12.5em;
}
```