# Center image with position relative in small screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a table of multiple pair image-description. In large screen the images are horizontal aligned. The problem is that, in small screens (xs) the images are not centered (the text yes).

I tried this code [Center position: relative div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35209317/center-position-relative-div)
This solution center the image, but it appears the horizontal scroll on mobile because of the margins.

js Fiddle of one image: https://jsfiddle.net/oca1wvmu/

HTML code (there are four images by row in large screen, but in mobile screen it only shows one by one):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 mt-2">
      <figure class="memberBoxImage">
        <img class="memberImgFront" src="https://placekitten.com/200/200">
        <img class="memberImgBack" src="https://lorempixel.com/200/200">       
      </figure>
      <div class="memberBoxDescription">
        <h4>Little text</h4>
        <p>More little text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 mt-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 mt-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 mt-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.memberBoxImage {
  position: relative;
}

.memberBoxImage img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.memberImgFront {
    z-index: 1;
}

.memberImgBack {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.memberBoxImage:hover .memberImgFront {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.memberBoxImage:hover .memberImgBack {
  visibility: visible;
}

.memberBoxDescription {
  margin-top: 210px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

To sum up, I want to center the image on small screen.

Comment: make sure you have a responsive viewport set up. It's worth a google :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the image itself is not centered, as it uses :

```
.memberBoxImage img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

You can center it horizontally, within the div by using:

```
.memberBoxImage img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

If you want to make sure it doesn't become bigger than the container, you could throw in `width: 100%;`.

Answer (score 0):

I used an other approach and got rid of the absolute positioning mostly.
Here a minimal example:

```css
.memberBoxImage img.memberImgFront {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.memberBoxImage:hover .memberImgFront {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 mt-2 text-center md-text-left">
      <figure class="memberBoxImage position-relative d-inline-block">
        <img class="memberImgBack" src="https://lorempixel.com/200/200">
        <img class="memberImgFront" src="https://placekitten.com/200/200">
      </figure>
      <div class="memberBoxDescription text-center">
        <h4>Little text</h4>
        <p>More little text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```